# "Commit Failed" when trying to upload files to github repository

Tags: git, github, upload

I was trying to upload a file to a repository in GitHub by dragging and dropping on the upload page.
However no matter how many times I tried the page keeps showing

## Commit failed

### Committing the files to the repository failed

I already tried using another browser, uploading a different file type (instead of .py, I tried to upload zip), and the webpage have not given me any clue of why it failed.
Most similar problem I found online occurs when using command line...

I'd very much like to know how I could upload a file(without downloading git)

~~ I've tried "or choose file" as well, but the result remain the same.
The file I tried to upload was merely 1kb... and the repository was actually empty.
Other problems I found online that seems to be alike mine mainly happened when they were using git bash (git commit), but I was simply trying to upload and commit files.
According to github's own instructions, all I have to do is click commit, and so I did...But I still got commit failed. orz
https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-file-to-a-repository/

Comment: What is the size of the file you trying to upload?

Comment: 1kb actually...

Comment: Does the file already exists in repo?

Comment: "Most similar problem I found online occurs when using command line" - could you clarify this?

Comment: Does using the link "Or choose your files" work. Please describe in details at which step it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing a similar problem. I tried doing a `git init` using Git Bash and then uploaded the files and it worked like a charm!

I think this happens when you try to upload a non-git repository directly to GitHub assuming that it would automatically create the git history.

Comment: My problem is strange. It was able to upload one folder but can't upload another folder. They are just java codes.